# Node using test for UI login

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, playwright

I use the following [blog](https://www.martinmcgee.dev/starting-microsoft-playwright/) to use the playright
login and I need something similar to use for my app, when I use the `headless:flase`
I see it opens the UI with the user password in however, it doesnt click on the logon button, I adopt the code I try with the following , am I missing something?

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://app.com');
  await page.fill('input[type="text"]', 'user@test.com');
  await page.fill('input[type="password"]', 'Abcd1234!');
  // page.click('div[data-testid="LoginForm_Login_Button"]');
  page.click('div[id="logOnFormSubmit"]');
}
)();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using

`page.click('div[id="logOnFormSubmit"]');`

There is no div in your given code example with that ID, but instead there is a button. You'd need to change that line to reflect this. The final code would look like below.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://app.com');
  await page.fill('input[type="text"]', 'user@test.com');
  await page.fill('input[type="password"]', 'Abcd1234!');
  // page.click('div[data-testid="LoginForm_Login_Button"]');
  page.click('button[id="logOnFormSubmit"]');
}
)();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! when the page is starting it open certificate popup (my user)  and then the user password screen ,is there a way to avoid it ?